The screen does not move when clicking on the navigation bar in Android Studio
I am working with Kotlin in Android Studio. I implemented a navigation bar, but the screen does not change, and I have no idea why. After implementing login and timer, I thought I would need a navigation bar, so I added it.
Since homeactivity is the screen that starts after logging in and has a navigation bar, I tried changing it to the start page, but it didn't work. I thought the navigation code was wrong, so I opened another file and implemented it there, and it worked fine.
So I'm guessing it's not the main activity?
HomeActivity
 package com.example.tutle

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.app.AlarmManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.app.TimePickerDialog
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
import com.example.tutle.databinding.ActivityHomeBinding
import java.util.Calendar

class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private val binding by lazy { ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n", "SimpleDateFormat", "ScheduleExactAlarm")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(binding.root)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }

        binding.DataTextView1.text = intent.getStringExtra("Data1") // Display received data

        binding.btnTimeset.setOnClickListener {
            val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            val currentHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
            val currentMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)

            // Create a TimePickerDialog to allow the user to select a time
            val timePickerDialog = TimePickerDialog(
                this,
                { _, hourOfDay, minute ->
                    // Set the alarm time to the time selected by the user
                    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay)
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute)
                    // Create a PendingIntent for setting the alarm
                    val alarmIntent = Intent(this, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
                    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                        this,
                        0,
                        alarmIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE // Add FLAG_IMMUTABLE flag
                    )
                    // Set the alarm using AlarmManager
                    val alarmManager = getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
                    alarmManager.setExact(
                        AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                        calendar.timeInMillis,
                        pendingIntent
                    )
                    // Display a toast message indicating that the alarm has been set
                    Toast.makeText(this, "The alarm has been set.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                },
                currentHour,
                currentMinute,
                true // Set in 24-hour format
            )
            // Display the TimePickerDialog
            timePickerDialog.show()
        }
    }
}


NaviActivity
 package com.example.tutle

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import com.example.tutle.databinding.ActivityNaviBinding

private const val TAG_USER = "user_fragment"
private const val TAG_HOME = "home_fragment"
private const val TAG_CAMERA = "camera_fragment"

class NaviActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding : ActivityNaviBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityNaviBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        enableEdgeToEdge()
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }

        binding.navigationView.setOnItemSelectedListener { item ->
            when(item.itemId) {
                R.id.mypageFragment -> {
                    setFragment(TAG_USER, mypageFragment())
                }
                R.id.homeFragment -> {
                    setFragment(TAG_HOME, homeFragment())
                }
                R.id.cameraFragment-> {
                    setFragment(TAG_CAMERA, cameraFragment())
                }
            }
            true
        }
    }

    private fun setFragment(tag: String, fragment: Fragment) {
        val manager: FragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
        val fragTransaction = manager.beginTransaction()

        if (manager.findFragmentByTag(tag) == null){
            fragTransaction.add(R.id.mainFrameLayout, fragment, tag)
        }

        val user = manager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_USER)
        val home = manager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_HOME)
        val camera = manager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_CAMERA)

        if (user != null){
            fragTransaction.hide(user)
        }

        if (home != null){
            fragTransaction.hide(home)
        }

        if (camera != null) {
            fragTransaction.hide(camera)
        }

        if (tag == TAG_USER) {
            if (user!=null){
                fragTransaction.show(user)
            }
        }
        else if (tag == TAG_HOME) {
            if (home != null) {
                fragTransaction.show(home)
            }
        }

        else if (tag == TAG_CAMERA){
            if (camera != null){
                fragTransaction.show(camera)
            }
        }

        fragTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss()
    }
}


cameraActivity
package com.example.tutle

import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat

class cameraActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera)
        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }
        showAlertDialog()
    }
    private fun showAlertDialog() {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        builder.setTitle("알림")
        builder.setMessage("카메라 액티비티에 오신 것을 환영합니다.")
        builder.setPositiveButton("확인") { dialog: DialogInterface, _: Int ->
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
        val dialog = builder.create()
        dialog.show()
    }
}

